# Absolutely positioned inline elements placed differently in Chrome 76+

Tags: html, css, css-position, chromium, display

## Problem

Since Chrome 76 absolutely positioned inline elements with no `bottom`, `left`, `right` or `top` properties are being placed differently.

## Example

View the snippet below in Firefox (69) and Chrome (76+). Chrome will display the `button` and `span` on a new line, while Firefox will display them next to the `label`.

```css
div {
  margin: 2em auto;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

button,
span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="text_field1">Example with button</label>
  <button>BUTTON</button>
  <input type="text" id="text_field1" value="Example value">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="text_field2">Example with span</label>
  <span>SPAN</span>
  <input type="text" id="text_field2" value="Example value">
</div>
```

## Expected behaviour

The `button`/`span` should be placed next to the `label`, not below it. It appears that Chrome is changing the `display` mode from `inline-block`/`inline` to `block` *(see [https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#dis-pos-flo)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#dis-pos-flo)_)* before it calculates where to place the element whereas Firefox and older versions of Chrome do this the other way around.

### Chrome 76 (Unexpected behaviour)

[image: Chrome 76]

### Chrome 75 (Expected behaviour)

[image: Chrome 75]

### Firefox 69 (Expected behaviour)

[image: Firefox 69]

### Edge 16 (Expected behaviour)

[image: Edge 16]

### Safari 12 (Expected behaviour)

[image: Safari 12]

## Browsers effected

Any Chromium based browser since version 76.

**Is this a bug or an intentional change to how Chromium will position elements under these conditions?**

**How can we position the element in a consistent manner across browsers?**

Comment: *How can we position the element in a consistent manner across browsers?* by setting top/left/right/bottom or you will fall into the static position and each browser has some freedom to calculate it

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443502/8620333 ... note the part :   *But rather than actually calculating the dimensions of that hypothetical box, user agents are free to make a guess at its probable position.*

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @TemaniAfif. Setting a `bottom`,`left`,`right` or `top` property is not an option in our use case as we want the element to display after the label text and we don't know how long that label will be. I agree it's by design, but it seems that the browsers are calculating things in different orders. Both make sense, but we would like a way to get a consistent output if possible without a complete refactor.

Comment: *we want the element to display after the label text* simply remove `position:absolute`, it's by default like that. Why the need of position?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good question! It's to be able to increase the click area of the element without it shifting the elements around it. We can achieve this in a different way, but would like to know why a change was made to Chromium which breaks this previously working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this a bug or an intentional change to how Chromium will position elements under these conditions?**

Yes it is a bug.

**How can we position the element in a consistent manner across browsers?**

The bug has been fixed in Chrome version 79.0.3908.2 so no action is necessary.

The bug report can be seen here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1001438#c19.